# Sendgrid on Heroku Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, heroku, smtp, sendgrid

I have setup Sendgrid for my Heroku Account, but the logs show the following issue when the app tries to send mail:

> Net::SMTPFatalError (550 Cannot receive from specified address <[the
>   email address I specified in devise.rb using config.mailer_sender]>:
>   Unauthenticated senders not allowed

My production.rb settings are:

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'heroku.com' }

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 587,
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name: ENV["my sendgrid username"],
    password: ENV["my sendgrid password"],
    domain: 'heroku.com'
  }
```

My Sendgrid password/username are obtained from Heroku using `heroku config -long`

Does anyone have any suggestion as to where the problem might lie? How can I grant the email address I have defined in config.mailer_sender authentication?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your user_name and password need to be the key names, not the values:

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    address: "smtp.sendgrid.net",
    port: 587,
    authentication: "plain",
    user_name: ENV["SENDGRID_USERNAME"],
    password: ENV["SENDGRID_PASSWORD"],
    domain: 'heroku.com'
  }
```

The idea being that you [keep the configuration separate to your code](http://www.12factor.net/config).

Comment: Jeez. What a muppet. I've been staring at it for hours. Thanks a lot.